# SQL Server 2012: distinct with over clause in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

What is the correct syntax of writing an aggregate function using `over (partition by)` ?

Or how could be this re-written? I don't have some sample table since I'm doing this as an exercise for myself. I wonder if this would be possible. Please find below, the scenario I was thinking of.

Let's take a simple example as a sample:

```
select 
    *,
    sum (column1 * column2) over (partition by column10, colum12)/100 as sumProduct
into #myTemp
from myTable
```

The query above works on a table which has those columns.
Now, how could I write the same thing for distinct values of `column1` and `column2`?

Query below is not working but it's the pseudo for what i'm trying to achieve.

The expected result is quite straightforward (see `distinct column1 * distinct column2` )

```
select 
    *,
    sum (distinct column1 * distinct column2) over (partition by column10, colum12)/100 as sumProduct
into #myTemp
from myTable
```

**EDIT:** I want to avoid `group by`. I'm trying to use partition by as much as I can so I would get better at window functions

Comment: You can't you distinct in windows function. First do a distinct in cte and then apply your function.

Comment: Aggregation or window functions -- except for `COUNT()` -- should not use `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use of `distinct` with an aggregation other than `count()` is generally not correct.  This is as true for window functions as it is for aggregation functions.

You can do the equivalent of `count(distinct)` using `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as CountDistinct
into #myTemp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column10, colum12 order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from myTable t
     ) t;
```

EDIT:

The above will count a `NULL` value as a "valid" value, unlike `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  This is easily remedied:

```
select t.*,
       count(case when seqnum = 1 then colum12 end) as CountDistinct
into #myTemp
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column10, colum12 order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from myTable t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Will this also work if, let's say, a value from `column` or `column2` is/will be `NULL`? Great answer

Comment: @CM2K . . . This treats `NULL` slightly differently because it counts it as a valid value.  I added a version that is consistent, even for `NULL` values.

Comment: I'm a beginner with `CTE` and `row_number()` (to be honest, only read briefly about them never used them). I understand the logic here (or, at least I hope), but how to calculate/incorporate  `sumProduct`  as showed in the question into your query?

Comment: @CM2K . . . I don't recommend doing that.

Comment: I understand, but that was the point of the question. Of calculating a `sumProduct` using `distinct` values in the partitioning. I understand that I can't write a query using `distinct` like that and I like your approach. But how to use your solution to perform a calculation like `sumProduct`? If the `sum(column1 *column2)` wasn't needed, I wouldn't go with a `cte` and would just think to use an additional subquery in the select or some similar aproach.

Comment: Using aggregation functions other than `count()` with `distinct` usually indicates a problem with the data structure, and I find it dangerous (of course, it is not ever necessary with `min()` or `max()`).  Either normalize your data or use `select distinct` in a subquery.